# Ember Data DS.Store.filter always returns empty list

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

After upgrading from Ember Data 1.0.0.beta3 to 1.0.0.beta7 my previously working calls to `DS.Store.filter` are always returning an empty list.  I can't find any mention in the release notes of such a fundamental change.  What could be going wrong?

Even something as simple as this returns nothing:

```
var results = store.filter('myModel', function() { return true; });
results.get('length'); // is always 0
```

This despite the Ember Chrome extension reporting 153 of these in my data store.

Comment: This code does not seem as though it is filtering anything. It rather seems as though you want to get the the length of the amount of a particular type of model that you have in the store that you can you do with store.find('mymodel').get('length') or something.

Comment: The example was just to illustrate that the collection was empty.  However, this was a semantics change between Ember Data beta 3 and 6 that changed the result from an array to a DS.PromiseArray.  https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1872.  Once I get my code working again i'll post the answer.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's async now, results.then(function(realResults){console.log(realResults.get('length'));}); you could also use results in the inside since I'm pretty sure they're using the promise proxy array

Comment: I see.. that is true i was looking for the beta 3 code because i only have the beta 7 code but it true its a Promise - PromiseArray I think you have it all figured. Nice hightlight!! it may bite someone else in the butt

Comment: Ya, I plan on contributing something to TRANSITIONS.md on Ember to talk about this.